# How to have Autohotkey write metadata, then extract that metadata for use in renaming the file

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I'm automating a process with Autohotkey where I'm renaming *old.xlsx* to *document_archived_on_%Timestring*, then renaming *current.xlsx* to *old.xlsx*, then renaming *newest_document.xlsx* to *current.xlsx*.

That part was straightforward and works fine.

I want to add a metadata comment to *newest_document.xlsx* that says "data_as_of_%Timestring%".  Later, I want to rename *old.xlsx* to "document_%metadata%.xlsx.

The simple, working script below:

```
;    Take newest report, rename it to current.  Take Current Report and move it to Old
;    Take oldest report and archive it.

;    Archive old report
FormatTime, Timestring, , yyyyMMdd
FileMove, G:\TPO_Project_DB\Old Data\old.xlsx, G:\TPO_Project_DB\Old Data\Eng_const_rpt_data_as_of_%Timestring%.xlsx

;    Rename and move "current.xlsx" to "old.xlsx"
FileMove, G:\TPO_Project_DB\Current Data\current.xlsx, G:\TPO_Project_DB\Old Data\old.xlsx

;    Rename and move newest report to current
FileMove, C:\TPOReports\Combined_eng_const_*, G:\TPO_Project_DB\Current Data\current.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a lot of information about reading the meta properties, but regarding writing to these..., well, I didn't find much. I didn't find a full solution, that is, examples of working code, but there may be at least two ways to do this.

Firstly, here are some reference links for reading the meta properties. If the links become dead, searching for "FGP - FileGetProperties" should yield similar results.

- [How to Access a file's metadata](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=27909)
- [[Function] FGP - FileGetProperties](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3806)

One method of writing to Excel's meta properties is to use COM. This likely isn't preferred as it would involve opening the file, writing the property, then saving - which may also be slow. For example, the code below (writes to the "Comments" meta property) took 4.2s to execute - though, only 0.4s after the Excel instance was created - so you may want to create the application object once until you've changed all the Excel file you need.

```
f1::
sFilePath := A_Desktop . "\test.xls"
oExcel := ComObjCreate( "Excel.Application" )
oExcel.Workbooks.Open( sFilePath )
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties( "Comments" ).Value := "Test text"
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
oExcel.Quit
Return
```

The other method involves using `DSOFile.dll` which can be found here, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224351/the-dsofile-dll-files-lets-you-edit-office-document-properties-when-yo
I know nothing about this or how to use it, but it was designed for manipulating Office products' properties and is likely much quicker than opening each file as shown in my code snippet above. Additionally, it *might* also not change the "Date modified" value.